# Do I need to build Jekyll for Github pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm working on a github pages workflow to help some non-techs update our website.

So far, I've been running `jekyll build` locally and then deploying the resulting folder to github pages, which works swimmingly.

On some review, it seems that much of the documentation implies that it should be possible to deploy just the Jekyll source files and have github automatically build the site and host it.

Is this possible, and if so, why can't I get it to work?

I've tried adding a new file to the _posts directory, and it seems that the 'Environment' tab of my repo shows that a build occurred, but the new post never shows up on the site.

Any suggestions would be *HUGELY* appreciated!

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll)?

Answer (score 1):

If your repository is named `<USERNAME>.github.io` then you can only use the `master` branch as the publishing source. For repositories named anything else you can use `gh-pages`, `master` or `/docs` on `master`.

In the case of any of these, you can push your source up to your repository on GitHub.com which will automatically trigger a build of your site.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the answer is that you can use jekyll source code, but only if it's in the gh-pages branch. If you use the docs/ folder or the master branch, it seems that you need to build locally before pushing (these options just allow you to host compiled HTML files rather than the raw jekyll source files).